# How to load script in React-native?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, razorpay

I want to load the script in my React native project. I would like to make a custom Razorpay payment. and we use typescript. I tried many ways but I am not getting a solution.  Please give me a solution if it works then I accept your answer Anyone here with a solution for this? Thanks in Advance. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/razorpay.js"></script>

var razorpay = new Razorpay({
            key: '<Key>', 
            image: 'https://i.imgur.com/n5tjHFD.png',
          });
          razorpay.once('ready', function(response: any) {
            console.log(response);
```

Comment: https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/react-native-integration/
razorpay support react native with `react-native-razorpay`

Comment: Yes, but we want to make it custom like this https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/web-integration/custom/ and we use typescript.